# Google Analytics - only track traffic to a folder of the site

Tags: google-analytics, subdirectory, user-tracking

I want to track traffic for `mysite.com/current-campaign/` and careless about traffic on `mysite.com` in general.

Is it ok to place the GA tracking code in the files inside the `/current-campaign/` folder or does it HAVE TO be in the root of the server for tracking to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GA will only track on the pages you actually put the tracking code on, regardless of where the page is located (unless you start messing with things like domain settings or filters etc..).

So IOW yes, it is okay to do that. If you don't have tracking code on mysite.com/somePage.html then it's not gonna track that page (though it might show up as the URL in some reports like referring URL or exit link or whatever, same as any other page you don't track)

Comment: I see. The problem I am having is that GA seems to tell me tracking is not installed. If I do install it on the root index.html (let's say), will I be able to filter trafic to mysite.com/myfolder/ if I only want to access stats for that?

Comment: It is not working for me, the code is within subfolder and it is not recording data neither showing real time data.

Answer (score 4):

In Google Analytics, you can add a filter to the profile and filter all but the chosen directories. Go to  Analytics Settings > Profile Settings and look for "Add Filter" link.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Crayon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5637606/1173184), you can limit tracking to a subdirectory by using `_setCookiePath()` function in your tracking function. See [Analytics documentation on single subdirectory](http://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#singleSubDirectory) (note the link anchor is not resolved to a correct header, at least for me).

This is advised in the documentation to use when you only want to track a subdirectory and avoid clashes with Analytics trackers possibly in use in other subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

I work for a department in a large university.
The department's web page resides at `www.some-uni.com/department-name/`.
I only have FTP access to the sub-folder `/department-name/` and nothing else on the site.

It was quite easy to get Google Analytics to track traffic within the subfolder `/department-name/`, ignoring the rest of the site. All I did was create a profile in GA, setting the default url to `www.some-uni.com/department-name/`. I then pasted the tracking code into the pages I wished to track.

It took about eight hours for anything to show up in GA, but after that it worked just fine.